# Can Cassandra Perform Joins Like the MySQL tables?

Tags: node.js, cassandra, express-cassandra

While i was working with a project (a playground project with nodeJS) I found that there is no joining option in the cassandra-nodejs ORM. Is there any option to have this in any ORM in built (except raw query).

I tried lots of tutorials and Node Library search but not found a suitable solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform joins in Cassandra. If you have designed a data model and find that you need something like a join, you’ll have to either do the work on the client side, or create a denormalized second table that represents the join results for you.

Reference Link [https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/stable/cassandra/data_modeling/data_modeling_rdbms.html#:~:text=No%20joins,the%20join%20results%20for%20you](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/stable/cassandra/data_modeling/data_modeling_rdbms.html#:%7E:text=No%20joins,the%20join%20results%20for%20you).

Comment: Like you've found out, Apache Cassandra® is a lightening fast NoSQL distributed database and joins aren't supported there. You can leverage a variety of freely available training materials like [Academy](https://datastax.academy/) and [this free browser-based training courses](https://www.datastax.com/dev) to get to know more about working with Cassandra.

Comment: Alternatively, if you're working with JSON like structures, you don't even have to design a schema and use [this data api](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra/astra-db-vector/api-reference/data-api.html). Welcome to Cassandra!